# How to enter into a editable "p" with an id when the enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" id="main"></p>
```

I want to enter the "main" p when I press the Enter Key. JS Code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.code === 'Enter' || e.code === 'NumpadEnter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(document.getElementById("main").innerHTML == "sudo apt update") {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "checking for updates...";
        }
        newLine();
        
    }
});
```

I tried to google how to do it but I couldn´t find a way to do it.

Comment: If by _enter the "main" p_  you mean show the cursor, you can use `document.getElementById("main").focus()`

Comment: What do you mean by 'enter'? You should use an input field, not a paragraph, to insert something.

Comment: Your code works, what do you need to do by `newline()`?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/xxJKeZO?editors=1011 Are you looking for like this one?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should probably use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`.
2. In case you want to do something else with the event of a different key move the `preventDefault` within the inner condition.
3. Use [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) to move the cursor to the editable paragraph element.

```js
// Cache the element
const main = document.querySelector('#main');

// Add a listener to the element
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKey);

function handleKey(e) {
  if (e.code === 'Enter' || e.code === 'NumpadEnter') {

    // Prevent the event from adding a return in
    // the element, `focus` on the element, and then update
    // its text
    if (main.textContent === 'sudo apt update') {
      e.preventDefault();
      main.focus();
      main.textContent = 'checking for updates...';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="main" contenteditable>sudo apt update</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter into the p element with the main ID when the Enter key is pressed, you can use the focus method:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.code === 'Enter' || e.code === 'NumpadEnter') {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(document.getElementById("main").innerHTML == "sudo apt update") {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "checking for updates...";
        }
        newLine();

        // Focus the main element
        document.getElementById("main").focus();
    }
});
```

This will give the p element with the main ID focus, which will allow the user to type into it. Note that you may also need to handle the blur event on the element to ensure that it remains focused when the user clicks outside of it.